# template specialization compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-specialization

I have a main.cpp and a header file called bar.h
This is the main.cpp. My goal is to have the program print out "bar":

```
#include "bar.h"

struct Raw{
};

template<typename Obj>
struct IsBar{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename Obj, bool>
struct function{
    static void callbar(Obj obj){ 
        obj.bar();
    }; 
};

template<typename Obj>
struct function<Obj, false>{
    static void callbar(Obj obj){ 
        std::cout<< "no bar()" << std::endl;
    }; 
};

int main()
{
    typedef Bar<Raw> Obj;
    Obj obj;

    function<Obj, IsBar<Obj>::value> f;
    f.callbar(obj); 

    return 0;
}
```

For the bar.h:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar{
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout<< "bar" << std::endl;
    };
};

template<>
struct IsBar<Bar>{ // I know this wouldn't work, but how do I do something like Bar<Raw> instead of just Bar?
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

Compiler gave me this error:  error: 'IsBar' is not a class template.
Previously I tried to have the content of bar.h inside the main.cpp, and everything works fine, because Raw is known when I declared the `IsBar<>` specialization using `Bar<Raw>`.

Comment: The template must be defined before the specialization of it.

Comment: Of course you can do `template<> struct IsBar<Bar<Raw>>`, or even `template<typename T> struct IsBar<Bar<T>>`, but the primary template must be visible when you add the specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization), e.g.

```
template<typename T>
struct IsBar<Bar<T>> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

That means for all the instantiations of `Bar<T>`, `IsBar<Bar<T>>::value` is `true`.

Note that the primary template should be declared before the specialization; I think you should move the primary template definition of `IsBar` from `main.cpp` to `bar.h`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/glxiFwCXkmiFLDcE)

Comment: I am still getting the same error, saying error: 'IsBar' is not a class template

Comment: @user1701840 Answer revised.